# ZSH 'Sticky' Prompt

Tags: macos, bash, terminal, zsh, oh-my-zsh

I have my ZSH theme outputting the status of my Vagrant/VBox VMs using `RPROMPT='$(vbox_status)'` in my .zsh-theme file (where `vbox_status` calls [a script which outputs what's running](https://gist.github.com/grega/61355d041ccfaef66419)), like so:

[image: ZSH theme]

However, I'm wondering if there's a way I can make this output 'sticky' so that, rather than outputting at the end of every single line, it will stay at the position indicated by the arrow and simply update itself whenever a new line is output above.

eg.

[image]

Comment: You don't need (or really want) to do this in the prompt.  In zsh, look into the functions `preexec` and `precmd`.  For bash, look into PROMPT_COMMAND and setting a DEBUG trap.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do this with a command called `tput`.

I have made a basic script which puts a string in the corner of the screen which will get you started.  You can make it much nicer by erasing things and highlighting or whatever but this is a starting point:

```
#!/bin/bash
screen_w=$(tput cols)   # Get screen width.
screen_h=$(tput lines)  # Get screen height.
str=$*                  # String to put in corner.
string_w=${#str}
let "x = $screen_w - $string_w"

tput sc               # Save current position
tput cup $screen_h $x # Move to corner
echo -ne $str         # Put string in the corner
tput rc               # Go back to saved position.
echo " >"             # Some kind of prompt
```

So you can set your prompt to run this like this (I called the above script pr.sh)

```
PS1=$(pr.sh $(date))
```

It might be different in `zsh` but I'm sure you can work that part out.
Just change the $(date) part to your status command. (pr.sh must be on your path)

This is a bit clunky, but it will get you started.  There is almost no limit to what you can do with  `tput`!

Comment: Brilliant, that does the trick! I've updated my Gist to show the full solution with ZSH: https://gist.github.com/grega/61355d041ccfaef66419

Comment: Example with no VMs running: https://www.evernote.com/shard/s153/sh/6bc2d85e-d9b7-4a69-8cf5-b831b0bd90ec/680ec902d7d540f94ace5aff5d80f6f6/res/5b3085c0-f003-4d26-ac9c-2fbe4d4ecccf/skitch.png?resizeSmall&width=832

Comment: Example with 1 VM running: https://www.evernote.com/shard/s153/sh/cf208c18-9d87-47d0-afb2-4b19c28662b8/8758ef7286dfc035381ab1e2f5d3c28f/res/8a47b88d-cb78-4519-9857-040a7c93e91c/skitch.png?resizeSmall&width=832

Comment: Thanks for the fun question.